# Can you access event data from i element onclick?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I currently am mapping through some icons which all hold a particular value (the icon type and value are being passed via props)

My issue is I want to have a click event that will update the state to hold the certain keys and values/id's etc from the onClick event.

Here's my state:

```
state = {
    activity_id: '',
    rating: '',
    log: ''
  }
```

Here's the event change handler:

```
  changeHandler = e => {
    this.setState(
      {
        activity_id: e.target.id,
        rating: e.target.value,
        log: e.target.name
      },
      () => console.log('SUBMITTED:', this.props.user_id, this.state)
    )
    this.props.addRecord(this.props.user_id, this.state)
  }
```

Here's where the onClick event occurs:

```
      <Grid.Column align="center">
        {this.props.smiles.map((smile, key) => {
          return (
            <a key={key}>
              <i
                className={
                  'far ' + `${smile.mood}` + ' fa-3x facesInCss'
                }
                value={smile.value}
                id={this.props.act_id}
                name={this.props.name}
                onClick={this.changeHandler}
              />
            </a>
          )
        })}
      </Grid.Column>
```

At the moment I'm only receiving something like this when I click on the second list item:

```
{activity_id: "2", rating: undefined, log: undefined}
```

What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What does your `smiles` data look like?

Answer (score 1):

You can directly pass the values to your handler rather than reading from event param.

```
changeHandler = (e, activity_id, rating, log) => {
    this.setState(
      {
        activity_id: activity_id,
        rating: rating,
        log: log
      },
      () => console.log('SUBMITTED:', this.props.user_id, this.state)
    )
    this.props.addRecord(this.props.user_id, this.state)
}

<Grid.Column align="center">
  {this.props.smiles.map((smile, key) => {
    return (
      <a key={key}>
        <i
          className={'far ' + `${smile.mood}` + ' fa-3x facesInCss'}
          value={smile.value}
          id={this.props.act_id}
          name={this.props.name}
          onClick={(e) => this.changeHandler(e, this.props.act_id, smile.value, this.props.name)}
        />
      </a>
    )
  })}
</Grid.Column>
```

Answer (score 1):

***The HTML  element represents a range of text that is set off from the normal text for some reason. Some examples include technical terms, foreign language phrases, or fictional character thoughts. It is typically displayed in italic type.***

***This element only includes the global attributes.***

```js
function handleClick(e){
  console.log('hello');
  console.log(e)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<i id='1' onclick="handleClick()">The lightning</i>

</body>
</html>
```

Look at the example when you use onclick on `<i>` tag it doesn't passes event object. so you get undefined.

But if you want to use this tag in the way you written than you need to pass the value explicitly to function.

```js
function handleClick(e){
      console.log('hello');
      console.log(1)
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<i id='1' onclick="handleClick(1)">The lightning</i>

</body>
</html>
```

**Global attributes reference** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes

**i tag reference** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/i

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing the event which you're trying to read values from. Simply changing

`onClick={this.changeHandler}`

to

`onClick={e => this.changeHandler(e)}`

would call the function on click, and pass it what it needs.

Also, no need to bounce stuff around. You're getting props, asinging them to `i` during a map, and then passing them to the function. Why not just do:

```
this.setState(
  {
    activity_id: this.props.act_id,
    rating: e.target.value,
    log: this.props.name
  },
)
```